# If a namedtuple is immutable, why does it have a _replace method?

Tags: python, namedtuple

Please consider this code:

```
>>> point = namedtuple('point', ('x', 'y'))
>>> p1 = point(3,4)
point(x=3, y=4)
>>> id(p1)
2881782633456  # address in memory

>>> p1._replace(x = 78)
point(x=78, y=4)
>>> id(p1)
2881782633456  # same as before.
```

Seems like i mutated the `namedtuple` in-place i.e. it is a mutable object. But it says everywhere that `tuple`s and `namedtuple`s are both immutable objects. I am confused.

Furthermore, if it is an immutable object, why does it have a `_replace` method?

Comment: You didn't even check to see if you'd mutated `p1`. This is the same behavior you'd see with, say, `str.replace`, which also doesn't mutate anything.

Comment: Methods that mutate the object in-place return `None` by convention; the fact that you see a `point` returned from the method call should suggest that a new object has been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tuple` is definitely immutable. If you print the p1, its same even after `_replace` function.

```
>>> point = namedtuple('point', ('x', 'y'))
>>> p1 = point(3,4)
>>> p1
point(x=3, y=4)   #same before _replace
>>> p1._replace(x = 78)
point(x=78, y=4)
>>> p1
point(x=3, y=4)  #same after _replace
```

*why do you have _replace then?*
It aims to return a new instance of the named tuple replacing specified fields with new values. It does not mutate the actual tuple itself. The operation is short lived.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't assign it back, so replace this line:

```
p1._replace(x = 78)
```

With:

```
pi = p1._replace(x = 78)
```

For it to be different.

Answer (score 1):

The _replace method creates a new namedtuple, it doesn't mutate the original, so immutability is preserved.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace):

> Return a new instance of the named tuple replacing specified fields with new values